# JSF 1.2 text to Javascript text. How to escape backslashes

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-1.2

I have this text in my JSF bean:

```
"\\name"
```

On JSF page it looks like this:

```
"\name"
```

Now, I want pass this string to the javascript function

```
 function showAlert(name) {
     alert(name);
 }

 <h:commandLink onclick="showAlert(#{myData.name})">
     <h:outputText value="#{myData.name}"/> 
 </h:commandLink>
```

However in firebug console I get error, which says that :

```
 SyntaxError: illegal character
 var a=function(){showAlert(\\name);};var b=function...
```

What is wrong with this code? One backslash escapes other backslash, however I still get this error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Aren't you missing quotes to make it a Javascript String? Note that JSF is entirely irrelevant in this question, you have a javascript error. How that javascript was generated is entirely besides the point.

Comment: Do you mean " '\\name' "?

Comment: Thank you both of you, Gimby I would accept your reply as an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simply that the generated javascript is lacking quotes to make the value a javascript string. Ex after JSF/Java has finished constructing the view, the resulting javascript call that ends up in the page content processed by the browser needs to be this:

```
var a=function(){
  showAlert('\\name');
};
```